# ¿Cómo crear un multiselect combobox en extjs 3.2.1?

Tags: extjs

Tengo un panel, y dentro del varios componentes, uno de ellos este combobox, habría alguna manera de poner hacerlo multiselect en vez de que seleccione solo un valor?

```javascript
    {
    xtype : 'combo',
    id : 'cmbSociedad',
    allowBlank : true,
    forceSelection : true,
    autoLoad : true,
    blankText : campoNoVacio,
    fieldLabel : contratoBuscadorSociedadKonecta,
    emptyText : contratoBuscadorBlankTextSociedadKonecta,
    store : storeSociedades,
    displayField : 'nombreCif',
    valueField : 'id',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    mode : 'local',
    typeAhead : false,
    editable : true,
    triggerAction : 'all',
    width : 500,
    value : ''
    }
```

Comment: Te recomendaría que mires [ask] para qué tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, haz él [tour]  para entender como funciona obtener tu primera medalla.

Comment: @DanyParedes Sinceramente más claro no puede estar, si no lo entiendes pues no lo sé

Comment: este ejemplo quizás te pueda ayudar a encontrar la solución. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jhv&view/editor

Comment: No vale con la versión 3.2.1 @DanyParedes